# How to access each element in a list of a list of strings

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of strings where I'm trying to grab each element however, I can only return each character within the list.

My list is `verify_value` which is a list (confirmed by printing the type) and `verify_value` contains the following list.

```
["[' First Payment Date', 'First Payment Date', 'First Payment Date(8)', '   First Payment Date', 'First Payment Date(4)',' First   Payment Date', ' First   Payment Date(11)', ' First\\xa0\\xa0 Payment Date']", "['   Payment Due Date', ' Payment Due Date', 'Payment Due Date', '  Payment Date', ' Payment Date', 'Payment Date']"]
```

I would like to access each element (e.g. ' First Payment Date', 'First Payment Date',etc.) however the below code only returns each character. Is there a way to access each element (I would prefer not to loop through each character if possible. ):

```
for i in range(0, len(verify_value[i])):
    for elem in verify_value[i]:
        print(elem)
        i+= 1
```

output:

```
F
i
r
s
t
...
```

Also, my list may contain hidden characters so using split may not work. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why wouldn't `.split()` work? You could try using `.split(',')` right?

Comment: @PCM when I do that, it would return each letter still. Sujay answer solves the issue, apparently the list isn't really a list but a string (even though in the code I created a list)

Answer (score 3):

The list you provided is a **string** representation of the list. You should use `ast.literal_eval()` to safely evaluate the list.

once you have done that, you can easily access the rest of the elements.

```
import ast
l1=["[' First Payment Date', 'First Payment Date', 'First Payment Date(8)', ' First Payment Date', 'First Payment Date(4)',' First Payment Date', ' First Payment Date(11)', ' First\xa0\xa0 Payment Date']", "[' Payment Due Date', ' Payment Due Date', 'Payment Due Date', ' Payment Date', ' Payment Date', 'Payment Date']"]
l2=[ast.literal_eval(i) for i in l1]
for element in l2:
    for j in element:
        print(j)
```

Comment: Thank you!! This works, I implemented in my code and the results come back the way I want it. I do have a question, why is it a string representation of the list? What determines this?

Comment: The list you see is inside ```""```. Python evaluates anything inside ```"" / ''``` as strings, be it any data type. @MartinW